# How can I make an DIV stretch to the bottom of the page after scrolling

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make an webpage with the following design:

All looks fine, however, if the content from the right spills out the page and I have to scroll down, the left menubar ("second_navbar") does not stretches to the end of the page.

I have tried changing "position" to absolute and adding "bottom" attribute equal to 0 but with no succes.

How can I make the left navbar to stick to the top navbar while stretching to the bottom at the page after scrolling?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

EDIT: I added the content on the left, the problem is evident if you minimze the window and scroll down to see the text

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: rgb(93, 87, 87, 0.5);
  color: rgb(93, 87, 87);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#navbar {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(93, 87, 87);
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#navbar li {
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

#second__navbar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

#second__navbar  li{
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 15% 0 0 15%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <p>My Name</p>
  </div>
  <div >
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="second__navbar">
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:50%; margin: 20% 20% 20% 20%">
           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would update your code to include how you are putting content into the right side area. Right now there is no content in the right side nor do you have any code for the content to be displayed in the right side.

Comment: Thanks, I did that!

Comment: `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` well a class with height OR a top and bottom padding and/or margin would probably be better than all that that

Comment: True, I modified as suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `display: flex` and re-arranged some container divs to get what you are looking for (I think!). Take a look at [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn how to use flex. Generally I use flex to arrange container elements but don't use flex for the smaller elements of your page like paragraphs of text. I also needed to add `height: 100%` to `html`. Get very friendly with your browser developer tools to see which elements are not arranged the way you expect them to be.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: rgb(93, 87, 87, 0.5);
  color: rgb(93, 87, 87);
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#navbar {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(93, 87, 87);
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#navbar li {
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.content-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#second__navbar {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#second__navbar li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.content {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    My Name
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
      <li>TITLE</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <ul id="second__navbar">
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
      <li>SUBTITLE</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```